# New Google Places Autocomplete crashes on Click

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I used new dependency of Google places. And app crashes when click on the Autocomplete View. Error is as follows.,

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Place Fields must be set.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:889)
    at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.dt.onClick(Unknown Source)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6207)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11094)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23639)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

The Initiating method. I used this inside a Fragment so I used to getFragmentManager() in initialize the Fragment.

```
private void setUpLocationPicker(){

    if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(this.getActivity(), getString(R.string.google_maps_key));
    }

    // Initialize the AutocompleteSupportFragment.
    AutocompleteSupportFragment autocompleteFragment = (AutocompleteSupportFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName() + ", " + place.getId());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

And the XML layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pickup_address" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Why autocomplete View Returns null in Onclick event. How to solve this?

Comment: have you try with `getChildFragmentManager()`

Comment: @TejasPandya Yes. Got the same Result.

Comment: @KZoNE have you found the solution? I am getting same error

Comment: @KZoNE , Have you found the solution  ? getting same error on newer versions, but not on older ones.

Comment: Yes @AbhayBohra Create a Place client first, the define the fields which you want to read from the API as "// Specify the fields to return.
        placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG);" and it is good to go. I'll post the full answer bellow

Comment: Thanks For the reply...but i am getting autocompleteFragment as null when i try to set place fields.Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way of doing this and post the answer here.

```
   // Initialize place API
    if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
        Places.initialize(mContext, mContext.getString(R.string.google_maps_key));
    }
    PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(mContext);

    // Create a new token for the autocomplete session. Pass this to FindAutocompletePredictionsRequest,
    // and once again when the user makes a selection (for example when calling fetchPlace()).
    AutocompleteSessionToken token = AutocompleteSessionToken.newInstance();

    // Specify the fields to return.
    List<Place.Field> placeFields = Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG);
```

additionally I got the answer from the [Place Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration). Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

late answer if it is helpful for someone.In my case `android:noHistory="true"` making the problem as i made `android:noHistory="false"` it started work again